# HTML Form Input and Help Text

Tags: html, accessibility

We have a many HTML forms in our application. Corresponding link to help documentation which is prepared by the content team for each page is given at the top of the page. But this does not make sense for blind people and even much for regular users as each time they need to go to the link which opens a separate page.

How can I display help text for the input boxes with content present in different page which is relevant to the current input ?

For visually challenged users I can use "aria-required" and "aria-describedby" flags if there is a way to link to that documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help text really should be on the same page as the form. You can always use an accordion or some other method to collapse or show/hide the docs.

If the content really does have to live at a separate URL, I suppose you could make an AJAX request to the corresponding HTML page to pull the content in upon user request for it, but make sure to use [ARIA Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) so users of assistive technology will know that the new content has been loaded.

Also, this may be helpful: [WCAG 2,G184: Providing text instructions at the beginning of a form or set of fields that describes the necessary input](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/G184)